# Common Practice for router setup in a business

Tags: router, redundancy

At the company that I'm working for, we have one router (SonicWall TZ 210) and it occasionally go down during business hours. All I have to do to bring it back up is to power cycle the router but during this time all employees in the company has no access to the server, email, file, etc.

How does business deal with unexpected down time because the router needs to be rebooted? What is the common practice to setup something to prevent something like this? Is there a redundancy/backup router?

Comment: Your first step: Investigate why the router needs to be rebooted and get another one if necessary. Every decent device fit for a business will work for years without a reboot.

Comment: Any advice on how I can go about investigating that? The router would work fine for weeks or months then all of the sudden it would just stop responding and a reboot is required.

Comment: look in it's logs.

Comment: How does it deal with unexpected downtime?  you've already tagged the question with "redundancy".  Are you sure you don't know the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be rebooting, trash it, maybe replace it. There are lots of options available for setting up redundant gateways, other network devices and even servers. Each manufacturer has their own way of doing this. It can also be done in software on regular servers for example with PFsense or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If your firewall is crashing regularly it could be a memory overflow from logging/reporting, or overloading the unit.

Start with the [defaults](http://documents.software.dell.com/sonicos/5.8/administration-guide/log/configuring-log-categories/log-categories?ParentProduct=639#1025916) and if you can, upgrade the firmware, the unit you have could be bad and is definitely out of warranty & discontinued.  The  bandwidth coming into that unit can't handle much more than a [50Mbps](http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/DS_TZ_Series_US.pdf) pipe (With IPS enabled)

Higher end units support HA Pairs, which monitor for failure and fail-over automatically.  You could also establish redundancy with OSPF and dual routers and dual ISPs and use routing and SLA policies on something like a L3 router.

If you are running a TZ210 you don't qualify for any of the built-in high-availability modes from SonicWall, like those available in the [TZ300](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/en/products/TZ300.html#tab=specifications)